# ASP.NET MVC 4 and Ext JS 4 Grid Panel

Tags: json, extjs, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I am developing ASP.Net mvc 4 Application using EF . 
 This is Client/index.cshtml (Before Adding ExtJS)

```
@model IEnumerable<Proj.Client>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name_Clt)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LName_Clt)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Birthday_Clt)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name_Clt)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LName_Clt)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Birthday_Clt)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID_Client }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID_Client }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID_Client })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I was following this blogpost , But I couldn't load data on it .
http://cincolabs.com/2012/04/10/asp-net-mvc-4-ext-js-4-gridpanel/

I created another ClientController .

```
   public JsonResult GetUsers()
        {
            var entities = new Entities();
            //What is important is to return the data as JSON.
            return Json(entities.Clients.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Should I remplace this code .

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var db = new Entities();
            return View(db.Clients.ToList());

        }
```

Another Question :

```
// Set up a model to use in our Store
    Ext.define('Client', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
        { name: 'First_Name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Last_Name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Email', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Date_Created', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'MS'}
    ]
    });

    var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Client',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/Examples/GetUsers',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'users'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

What does this mean "url: '/Examples/GetUsers'," !! Should I replace it in my case !!

Comment: It's working out , but I couldn't load Data . I got empty Grid !

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is a bit vague. I never worked with Ext JS but from your posted code, it seems to me that it creates it own table using the GetUsers function. The first View you posted is an Index View that Visual Studio can automatically create that displays your data. If your Ext JS is creating the table, then I suggest you replace Index View with the appropriate code to call the table data. Then the method GetUsers should be renamed as Index.

Your question regarding /Examples/GetUsers should be the url to the controller method that saves your data (something like /Client/Save).